# Accessing datatable data across different views?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have Primefaces datatable. It has 2 relevant columns. The first has inputText and commandlink that shows search popup. In popup, I select some value and then the popup closes and inputtext gets populated by that value. Now, in the second column I have another commandlink that opens another view where I can do some actions on the datatables row item. I need to somehow pass the populated inputtext's value to that other view. With that value I will retrieve items to put in dropdown list. I think I can't really set that value in backing bean because user can click on another datatable row, then click on first row's link and backing bean would pass incorrect data (second row's data to first row's link). I could pass datatable's var item to that other view, but how do I set its value from popup search result then? Do I have access to datatable's var in popup somehow?

Code:

```
<p:dataTable value="itemsList" var="item">
    <p:column>
         <h:inputText id="1" value=""/>
         <p:commandLink oncomplete="pfPopup.show();"/> // shows popup where i perform search and populate inputText id="1"
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
    <p:commandLink value="Allocate" action="allocate"/> // After going to new view here, I need value from same row's inputText id="1". How can I pass that value when inputText gets populated so I can use it in this xhtml? I guess I need to set "item" field with that value and pass "item" to some method in new view? Can I update "item" from popup?
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

In popup I have this datatable:

```
<p:dialog id="popup" widgetVar="pfPopup" resizable="false" modal="true">
    <p:dataTable id="searchResults" var="result" value="#{searchBean.results}">
        <p:column>
        <p:commandLink id="selectResultNumber" oncomplete="pfPopup.hide();populateInputTextField();"/>
        </p:column>
     </p:dataTable>
</dialog>
```

Comment: Well you can help us understand your needs by providing some code.

Comment: Small question: is a different view a dialogFramework popup or should it be a new browser window?

Comment: dont ask questions in comments in code. Why not just make your popup modal?

Comment: The view is not dialog/popup. It is new new window. My popup is modal, just didn't write it here, I edited.

Comment: where do you even **try** to open the new window then?

Comment: I have datatable. In each row there are 2 commandlinks. First link populates some value in another column, the second link goes to new view in flow where I need the value from populated field.. But I am not sure how to pass that value.. Sorry if I am not clear..